# Categorical semantics of universe levels in dependent type theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, type-theory

I know that locally closed cartesian categories provide categorical semantics for type theories with dependent products.

What kind of categories model type theories with infinite universe hierarchies (cumulative or non-cumulative)?

Comment: What are you assuming about the universes? Just closure under $\Pi$?

Comment: At an elementary level, there isn't going to be an answer to this other than something like "LCCs with universes".  More interestingly, there are non-elementary ways to *construct* universes, e.g. in Grothendieck toposes if there are inaccessible cardinals in the ambient set theory.  Is that the sort of thing you're interested in?

Answer (score 4):

A *universe* in a category with display maps is a specified display map $\tilde U \to U$ (cf. Section 5.5 of Taylor's thesis [Recursive Domains, Indexed Category Theory and Polymorphism](https://www.paultaylor.eu/domains/recdic.pdf), or Section 9.6 of Taylor's *Practical Foundations of Mathematics*; the notation in this answer follows Voevodsky's [A C-system defined by a universe in a category](https://www.math.ias.edu/Voevodsky/files/files-annotated/Dropbox/Submitted%20papers/Csystem_fromauniverse/Csystem_fromauniverse_new.pdf)). Recall that objects represent contexts, and display maps represent projections from extended contexts, and so this display map can be interpreted as a term $X : U, x : X \vdash X : U$. We can extend a context $\Gamma$ by a $U$-small type $A$ (that is, a type in the universe $U$) by taking a pullback along the universe:

[image: extending a context]

The morphism $\Gamma, a : A \to \tilde U$ is viewed as picking out the type $A$ and the term $a  : A$. Conversely, any display map $\Gamma, a : A \to \Gamma$ that fits into a pullback square along the universe may be seen as an extension by a $U$-small type in this way.

We can therefore define a hierarchy of (non-cumulative) universes to be a family of display maps $\{ \tilde U_i \to U_i \}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ such that each $U_i$ is $U_{i + 1}$-small. One may additionally want to impose axioms on these universes asserting that they are closed under the type constructors appropriately.

Modulo coherence issues, a locally cartesian-closed category is a display map category, and so dependent type theories with dependent sums, dependent products, extensional identity types and universes are modelled by locally cartesian-closed categories with universes. (Mike Shulman points this out in the comments, but it's surprisingly difficult to find a definition of universe in this setting, so I thought it would be helpful to spell out.)

Comment: Somebody introduced categories with display maps and this definition of universes in his thesis in 1987.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: I should have thought to look there, thanks! I shall add a reference imminently.

Comment: For categories with display maps, [Chapter VIII of my book](http://paultaylor.eu/~pt/prafm/html/c8.html) is a much better account.  For universes, the [Andy Pitts' paper on Russell's paradox](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~amp12/papers/notrpl/notrpl.pdf) that also has my name on it, is probably the best early reference.